# How to avoid spaces between numbers when displaying TagBox(es)

Tags: notebooks, formatting, boxes

The instruction :

`DisplayForm[RowBox[List[0,1,Superscript[2,3],Superscript[1,2],a]]]`

displays a gap between the first two items of the list

[image]

but if one is careful not to have two consecutive integers, there is no gap

`DisplayForm[RowBox[List[0,a,1,Superscript[2,3],Superscript[1,2],a]]]`

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to disable (locally) the space inserted
by Mathematica between two integers in this case to have something like that:

[image]

I would like the result to stay a TagBox or InterpretationBox, easy to copy/paste,
if possible.

Comment: Out of upvotes for another 5 hours, otherwise +1, it's an interesting question.

Comment: @rcollyer Let me do that for you. I have some left  ;-)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I just needed a little patience. I've got 40 more upvotes to burn, who wants them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use `ToBoxes` (or `MakeBoxes`) to construct boxes, instead of doing it yourself?

```
DisplayForm[
 ToBoxes[Row[List[0, 1, Superscript[2, 3], Superscript[1, 2], a]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You are right, this is the correct way in general. The trouble was that I created these expressions incrementally, wanting to keep an easy way to retrieve the data into it, and got lost in the process.

Answer (score 6):

This is caused by the `AutoMultiplicationSymbol` option in the front end.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, AutoMultiplicationSymbol -> False]
```

Will make the space disappear.

Comment: or just use `Style` rather than set it globally: `DisplayForm[
 Style[RowBox[List[0, 1, Superscript[2, 3], Superscript[1, 2], a]], 
  AutoMultiplicationSymbol -> False]]`

Comment: I agree that setting the options globally for a FrontEnd or a Notebook is not what is wanted in general.  @mike : Or one can define/use a style with this option turned false.

Comment: @ragfield : your answer is correct and welcome because it outlines the mechanism causing the space in the first place. But Brett's answer is the one I will accept as it points out a more idiomatic way of producing the kind of objects I wanted initially.

Comment: You can also interpose `"\[InvisibleSpace]"` between arguments, which instructs the FE that we are definitely *not* doing multiplication. The advantage to `"\[InvisibleSpace]"` is that it can be applied more selectively. If you look at how the `Row` typesets in Brett's solution, you'll see that's what it's doing.

Comment: @John More specifically: `2\[InvisibleSpace]3` is interpreted *as multiplication* by the FrontEnd but is shown as `23` instead of `2×3`.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it might have to do with reserving space for an invisible plus sign. In that case wrapping the 1 in `NumberForm` would get rid of this nagging space (adding an explicit `NumberSigns` isn't necessary as `NumberForm` already has the correct default value for this option).

```
DisplayForm[RowBox[List[0, NumberForm[1], Superscript[2, 3], Superscript[1, 2], a]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this leaves me wondering why the space isn't there when you precede it with a character 'a'.